# Is there an alternative for iFrames in iOS?

Tags: ios, .net, pdf, iframe, viewer

I know there are unlimited threads about the issues with iFrames in iOS and Safari.  I was wondering if there are any alternatives.  I have a very basic website where I have a list of "educational" pdf files.  I want to allow a user to click on one, have it displayed on the site, allow them to "Return to List" and then click and display another.  The concept is straight forward and works fine in Windows/Android but without the use of objects or iFrames I can't get it to work in iOS.  These will be being used on an iPad.

Any direction is helpful.

Comment: try with https://github.com/PierBover/ios-iframe-fix

Comment: still loads without being able to scroll past the first page and is loading the .pdf as an image inside iframe, but thanks for your suggestion

Comment: its same happening in my case Nick